# ag-grid: call function every time filter is clicked

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

How to call a function every time the filter icon is clicked in ag-grid. Below is my code. My aim is to reset the filter values of `Name` column every time filter icon is clicked. I have to use `agSetColumnFilter`. I tried `filterParams` but it is not called every time but only ones Can anyone please guide me here?

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.columnDefs = [
      {
        headerName: "Name",
        field: "name",
        width: 150,
        filter: "agSetColumnFilter",
        menuTabs: ['filterMenuTab']
      }
    ];
  }

  onGridReady(params) {
    this.rowData = [
      {
        name: "A",
        flag: true
      },
      {
        name: "B",
        flag: false
      }
    ];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `postProcessPopup` callback (see documentation [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-menu/#repositioning-the-popup)). This callback is called every time you click on the filter icon.

Add your callback into your html:

```
[postProcessPopup]="postProcessPopup"
```

Then create your `postProcessPopup` function:

```
this.postProcessPopup = function(params) {
      if (params.column.colDef.field === 'name')
      {
        var athleteFilter = this.gridApi.getFilterInstance('name');
        athleteFilter.selectEverything();
        this.gridApi.onFilterChanged();
      }
    }.bind(this);
```

If the click filter icon is for the field `name`, then selecting everything for that filter, then call the `onFilterChanged` function on the `gridApi` to make sure it updates.

You can see a working Plunker [here](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/tZAj1uGSP8HbiCi8) (try filtering the "Athelete" field).

More documentation on the filter api can be found [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-api/).